# WordPress (Click to Deploy) on VM instance not accessible. PhpMyAdmin not accessible. SSH & FTP not accessible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine

The site was working well. Installed SSl from CertBot following the tutorial from this link - https://onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificates-wordpress-google-cloud-click-to-deploy/

The site resolved well after installing SSL. But here is what happened WordPress Admin did not allow me to update the plugins and so I tried to change the file permissions via SSH and something went wrong after that. The server crashed and it is not accessible via SSH, FTP, PHPMYADMIN and the site is throwing up error 'Error establishing database connection'.

Edited: I was trying to change the permissions of the /var/www/html folder but may be by mistake typed out wrong path or hit enter as /var/. My bad that I am not able to figure out what went wrong.

Thank you for the suggestions. Is there any link or tutorial which I can follow and get the steps done that you had suggested? I am quite naive to Cloud hosting setup.

Will I be able to recover the site and the database? I have written to Google Support but I am not getting answers from them yet.

Will the website work on the new instance and disk attached from the earlier instance? How can I go about this.

Comment: Which file permissions did you change? My guess is that you corrupted the file system security which means you cannot recover the instance. Create a new VM, attach this VM's disk to the new VM, and extract needed files. You could attach to the serial console to double-check what is going wrong during system boot. The repair will require mounting the disk on another instance.

Comment: This article has a section that shows how to mount the disk from one instance onto another. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/